# Net::HTTP::Proxy requests... how do you do it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, proxy

I am having trouble making a proxy call. How on earth do you make this happen?

Here is what I have so far:

```
proxy_addr = '162.243.105.128'
proxy_port = 6170

Net::HTTP::Proxy(proxy_addr, proxy_port).start('www.google.com') {|http| http}
```

I get:

```
#<#<Class:0x007f85d8a092d0> www.google.com:80 open=false>
```

When:

```
Net::HTTP::Proxy(proxy_addr, proxy_port).start('www.google.com') {|http| http.get('www.google.com')}
```

I get

```
#<Net::HTTPNotImplemented 501 Tor is not an HTTP Proxy readbody=true>
```

How do I make this work!

Answer (score 1):

> Tor is a SOCKS proxy, not an HTTP proxy.

I ran into the same issue. I don't think it is possible with plain `Net::HTTP`. Install http://socksify.rubyforge.org/

```
require 'socksify/http'
http = Net::HTTP::SOCKSProxy(addr, port)
puts http.get(URI('http://echoip.com'))
```

Comment: I'll give it a try today